# WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For compatibility reasons I prefer to use Chrome version 55.0.2883.75 with Chromedriver v. 2.26. I downloaded the older version of chrome from https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php and Chromedriver 2.26 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.26/.

I am using the following code to attempt to set my Chrome binary location:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chrome64_55.0.2883.75\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = options)
```

However, when I attempt to launch the WebDriver Python returns the following error:

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362
(5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

I have tried searching through similar questions and answers, but have not had any luck so far.

Comment: Try use single forward slashes instead of double back slashes

Comment: Thanks, but both single and double forward slashes return the same error above.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to find the **Chrome** binary in the default location for your system.

As per the [**ChromeDriver - Requirements**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver/01fde32d0ed245141e24151f83b7c2db31d596a4#requirements):

> The server expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for each system:
>
> | OS | Expected Location of Chrome |
> | --- | --- |
> | Linux | /usr/bin/google-chrome<sup>1</sup> |
> | Mac | /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome |
> | Windows XP | %HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe |
> | Windows Vista and newer | C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe |
>
> <sup>1</sup> For Linux systems, the **ChromeDriver** expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a *symlink* to the actual *Chrome binary*.

---

### Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location

However you can also override the default *Chrome binary location* as follows:

To use *Chrome version 55.x* installed in non standard location through *ChromeDriver v2.26* you can use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chrome64_55.0.2883.75\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print("Chrome Browser Invoked")
driver.quit()
```

[Related Docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location)

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Is Chrome installation needed or only chromedriver when using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330322/is-chrome-installation-needed-or-only-chromedriver-when-using-selenium/62449076#62449076)

Comment: This worked, thank you. For future reference, I put both the chrome and chromedriver executables in the same directory.

Comment: where can I download chrome binary for linux?

Comment: What about Windows 10? It does not work with a link named "chrome.exe" in the path shown for Vista.

Comment: Update 2019: use options=options instead of chrome_options=options

Comment: I read another comment that said I might need to install Chrome itself, not just the wrapper from selenium called 'chromedriver' -- the .so on my Chromebook.

so i finally managed to run the following command to install my Chrome executable, and then things worked.

it's weird to think you have to (re?)install Chrome on a Chromebook, but the Linux VM didn't seem to be able to find it. maybe I just didn't know where to look.

    `> sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: It's probably a version thing, but on my system the setting is `options.BinaryLocation`.

Comment: google-chrome-stable --version
Google Chrome 121.0.6167.139 
chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 121.0.6167.139
 pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 4.17.2
 but still the error..

Answer (score 4):

What happened to me is that I didn't have chrome, the main browser, installed.
Download the browser and it fixes this issue.

Comment: i wish i could switch to my own cefsharp embed on panel iinstead of the chrome installed.

Comment: oh thank you, I have been using Brave browser, thinking "yeah this is chrome" but no it's not. downloading actual chrome fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using an old version of chrome driver with the latest Google Chrome locally gave me the same exception.

Just go to the [ChromeDriver page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and make sure you have the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, there is a new bug causing the same error even if Chrome is installed at the default place. This is because the new chromedriver is [looking for "Google Chrome for Testing.app" instead](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing/issues/30#issuecomment-1643668565).

I did the following:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@stable
mv chrome/mac-115.0.5790.102/chrome-mac-x64/Google\ Chrome\ for\ Testing.app /Applications
rm -rf chrome
```

**Update:** The latest version seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue in MacOS. Even after setting binary path in chromeoptions, it didn't work. It got fixed after installing `npm i chromedriver`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by installing Google Chrome [link](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=BNSD&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIiv-z2O6-9gIVMwWiAx1W_A74EAAYASAAEgLfPPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and it solved problem automatically (I use Kali Linux) and be sure that it is installed to the "/usr/bin"(default it is downloaded to here).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31269257)

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to download Chrome from the actual website.  I ran into the same problem, but I had downloaded Chrome from the Ubuntu software package manager.  I uninstalled the package manager version and installed from the website, and the error resolved.  Same issue could probably arise installing from other package managers.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error because i installed Chrome with flatpak then Selenium doesn't find the directory of the Driver. Then i installed Chrome with Fedora Store and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to solve my problem

```
private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void StartBrowser() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://opt//WebDriver//bin//chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/");}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way;
Download `chromedriver` and `chrome version` [except 115.0.5790.110 (it does not work properly)] from this link : [chrome-for-testing](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

1. Put the chrome driver in the chrome path
2. Replace the below path with your Chrome version path

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome Dev/Application/chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
#################
driver.get('https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue when I was trying to use chrome driver win64 instead of win32(in my case)

Answer (score -1):

Check https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started
You can specify the binary path in the constructor of the webdriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
```

Comment: That is for the path to the webdriver binary, no? I think what I need is how to correctly specify the chrome binary.