# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 though Chrome v74 is installed

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am starting to play around with selenium in python, and when i try to run this code it just pops an error that this version of chromedriver only supports version 74 of chrome, but I already downloaded version 74 from here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/

The code i am trying to run:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
driver.quit()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Main/Desktop/Python web bot/Bot 
code/selenium_training.py", line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

As you can see, it says that I need version 74 chrome, but i already have it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* expects the *Chrome Browser* version to be **74**.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=74.0.3729.6*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=74.0.3729.6*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

Presumably you have multiple versions of *Chrome* browsers installed within your system and the version of *Chrome* browser installed at the default location which is accessed by **chromedriver=74.0.3729.6** is **not** *Chrome Browser v74.0*. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

The quickest solution would be to upgrade *Chrome* version installed at the default location to ***Chrome v74*** level.

---

### Alternative

As an alternative, if you want to use the *Chrome* browser binary installed in a **non-standard location** you can use an instance of `ChromeOptions()` with the `binary_location` property to point to the *non-standard Chrome Browser location* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chrome64_55.0.2883.75\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
print("Chrome Browser Invoked")
driver.quit()
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c/50140554#50140554)

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Answer (score 0):

Run a search on your computer for "chromedriver" files, then delete all the searched files and copy the latest driver in your desired driver folder. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mayur. Thanks for your short answer. Could you give some more details to it, please? How and where to search for `ChromeDriver` files? Are there any standard locations where these drivers are installed/should be place? By the way, just have a look into the HelpCenter regarding [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This most commonly happens when chrome itself updates, but you have not updated the local ChromeDriver version to match your locally installed version of chrome.

In chrome, click the three dots, in the upper right, Help --> About Google Chrome.  this will show your version of chrome.  Or chrome://settings/help

Download the same version from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Save that to the path defined, as in @DebanjanB's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to chrome and check the version of chrome in your PC. (help -> About Chrome)
Download the same version ChromeDriver from the below link ...

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

then extract it and do paste in your script folder.