# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Our Python code worked 6 months ago completely fine. Now half a year later we get the following error:

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)

According to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928713/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-created-this-version-of-chrome), it sounds like Chrome updates every few months and we may have the wrong Chrome version. However, many of the solutions from multiple articles did not change much (will go in more detail on bottom).

Here is my code where the issue most likely is:

```
import requests #API package for Chrome
import json #Package to send json data variables JavaScript variables
import pandas as pd #Data frames
import csv # Excel *.csv IO
import datetime as dt # date and time
import os #DOS operating system
from time import sleep #sleep function
from selenium import webdriver #internet web scraping
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #internet web scraping

# set up the profile 
profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  # This is how we configure the Chom browser
prefs = {"download.default_directory": r'C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\weather',
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True}

profile.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs) #configureig Chrome browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\chromedriver.exe', options=profile) # crg ariver.

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\weather')
```

---

**What I tried:**
Replacing the [Chromedriver version](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/) on the desktop location here C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\chromedriver.exe'.  This is in case we now have the wrong version).

**Full Code** (this was working 6 months ago!):

```
import requests #API package for Chrome
import json #Package to send json data variables JavaScript variables
import pandas as pd #Data frames
import csv # Excel *.csv IO
import datetime as dt # date and time
import os #DOS operating system
from time import sleep #sleep function
from selenium import webdriver #internet web scraping
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #internet web scraping

api_key = '48d0585eb93c6d74105b8707996390e1' #Open weather API, ot used 

# The largest cities in North America
city_name = ['Atlanta','Baltimore','Boston','Charlotte','Chicago','Dallas','Denver','Detroit','Houston','Indianapolis','Kansas City','Los Angeles','Miami','Minneapolis','Montreal','Nashville','New York','Philadelphia','Phoenix','Pittsburgh','Portland','Riverside','Saint Louis','San Diego','San Francisco','Seattle','Tampa','Toronoto','Vancouver','Washingotn DC']

#indicies for each city on weather.com
city_id = [4180439,4347778,4930956,4460243,4887398,4684888,5419384,4990729,4699066,4259418,4393217,5368361,4164138,5037649,6077243,4644585,4560349,5128581,5308655,5206379,5746545,5387877,4407066,5391811,5391959,5809844,4174757,6167865,6173331,4366164]

#urls for each city in weather.com
city_url = ['https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USGA0028:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMD0018:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMA0046:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USNC0121:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USIL0225:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USTX0327:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCO0105:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMI0229:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USTX0617:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USIN0305:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMO0460:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA0638:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USFL0316:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMN0503:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/CAXX0301:1:CA',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USTN0357:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USNY0981:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USPA1276:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USAZ0166:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USPA1290:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USOR0275:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA0949:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USMO0787:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA0982:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA0987:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USWA0395:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USFL0481:1:US',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/CAXX0504:1:CA',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/CAXX0518:1:CA',
            'https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USDC0001:1:US']

# set up the profile 
profile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  # This is how we configure the Chom browser
prefs = {"download.default_directory": r'C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\weather',
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True}

profile.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs) #configureig Chrome browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\chromedriver.exe', options=profile) # crg ariver.

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\weather')

with open('weather_' + str(pd.Timestamp.today())[0:10] + '.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:  #output file for weather data.

    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',') # class to write to csv files.
    spamwriter.writerow(['city_id','city_name','datetime','offset','temp_high','temp_low']) # header row of the output file.

    for i in range(0,len(city_url)): #Grab the data from the site (Cycle through each city)
        print(pd.Timestamp.today())
        driver.get(city_url[i]) #Go to the url for each city.
        print(city_url[i])
        print(pd.Timestamp.today())

        for j in range(1,16): # cycling through the 16 dayts.

            # Grab high, low, and date for each city.
            high = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(j) + ') > td.temp > div > span:nth-child(1)').text
            low = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(j) + ') > td.temp > div > span:nth-child(3)').text

            date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + str(j) + ') > td:nth-child(2) > div > span').text

            #auth > div > div > div > div > div > form > button

            #twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div > span
            #twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div > span
            #converts a string to an integer
            if high[0] == '-':
                temp_high = 0
            else:
                temp_high = int(high[0:-1])

            if low[0] == '-':
                temp_low = 0
            else:
                temp_low = int(low[0:-1])
            #write out the row for each day.
            spamwriter.writerow([ city_id[i] , city_name[i] , date , (j-1) , temp_high , temp_low ])
#file closed
```

Comment: You need to have a chromedriver version that supports your local chrome installation version.

Comment: I did try replacing the Chromedriver version https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/ on the desktop location here: C:\Users\Trading\Documents\Python\dcm_trading\chromedriver.exe'.

Comment: But thank you for your reply we are going to get someone else to look at this i believe now that you confirmed the issue (I thought that was probably the issue)

Comment: What you need to check is what version of Google Chrome you are running. Then download the appropriate chromedriver.

Comment: Ok. I did that too actually so I was on the right track. We are using Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit).  Then I put (from the above comment) Chromedriver version 7.4 on the desktop spot.

Comment: In your above comment you are downloading chromedriver for version 74. Get the corresponding version from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Yes i went to your link which lead me to this link: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/   Then I downloaded the chromedriver_win32.zip version. And replaced it into the Chromedriver location spot on the desktop by deleting the old one.

Comment: You do understand that the link you are posting everytime specifically says version **74.0.3729.6** ? If you follow the link I posted, you can then go here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/ and download version 79...

Comment: Ok, think it worked thanks. Wow I was 99% there to the right solution I just for some reason thinking I needed 7.4 version because thats what the error message said. Thanks!!

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid search hits with Java.