# WebDriverException: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable or chrome binary not found

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing selenium test via Jenkins server in AWS Ubuntu.

I was getting chrome binary not found error so I set chrome binary in my code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/webdriver/chromedriver/linux64/83.0.4103.39/chromedriver");    
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", true);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.merge(capabilities);
options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); //Linux 
options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); //Windows
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Then the error changed to: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

```
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 14665
Only local connections are allowed.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
 INFO [main] (ControlCenter.java:108)- START
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 2.116 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] com.info.end2end.ExcelAccountToFusion.onTestSetup  Time elapsed: 2.032 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
**unknown error: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable**
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'jenkins-it02', ip: '10.113.0.187', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-1019-aws', java.version: '11.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

This is how my usr/bin is: 
[image: binary folders]

And this is message when I try to launch browser in command line:
[image: launch chrome]

I tried the solution given by @DebanjanB at [Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c) but no luck. Any help is much appreciated as I have spent 2 days on this already.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if `setBinary()` should be pointing to **`/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`**.

As per the documentation in [How To Install Google Chrome 78 On a RHEL/CentOS 7 and Fedora Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-google-chrome-on-redhat-rhel-fedora-centos-linux/) to install and use the latest [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) using *Yum* you need to follow the sequence below:

1. Open the Terminal application. Grab 64bit Google Chrome installer.
2. Type the following command to download 64 bit version of Google Chrome:

   ```
   wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
   ```
3. Install Google Chrome and its dependencies on a CentOS/RHEL, type:

   ```
   sudo yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_*.rpm
   ```
4. Start Google Chrome from the CLI:

   ```
   google-chrome &
   ```

Outputs from yum command:

[image: yum-google-chrome-command]

Finally, you need to use the following line to set the *chrome* binary:

```
options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Cannot find Chrome binary with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/cannot-find-chrome-binary-with-selenium-in-python-for-older-versions-of-google-c/50140554#50140554)

Comment: install instructions you provided is fro rpm based systems. Mine is Ubuntu which uses deb installation. I followed: https://itsfoss.com/install-chrome-ubuntu/#install-chrome-terminal adding force install to get all dependencies. 

I tried options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome"); but error remains the same.

I found I am unable to open chrome from CL but as root user it is working:

Comment: root@jenkins-it02:~# google-chrome
[15489:15489:0607/070913.642463:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
root@jenkins-it02:~# exit
logout

Comment: qa_user@jenkins-it02:~$ google-chrome
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/s3tools.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
google-chrome: command not found
qa_user@jenkins-it02:~$

Comment: Does this mean I can spawn chrome using root but not as qa_user?
My jenkins is set up as qa_user.
This is the root cause I arrived at after a lot of debugging but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: UPDATE:  I solved the 'could not open file' issue by giving permission to /etc/apt/sources.list.d for qa_user. Now the issue is I am unable to open chrome in CL.
qa_user@jenkins-it02:~$ whereis google-chrome
google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome.1.gz
qa_user@jenkins-it02:~$ google-chrome
google-chrome: command not found
qa_user@jenkins-it02:~$

Same command as root user gives: Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: 
After my below solution, I uninstalled Chromium and kept only Chrome for further testing. Surprisingly, chrome issue got fixed. I am able to run tests in Chrome now. Not sure how this is happening but I think it has something to do with dependency package that comes with Chrome.

I know this is strange but installing Chrome and Chromium and then uninstalling Chromium worked for me.

Comment: I used your trick and get working well for me too. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the actual fix for this issue but I could get around my actual blocker by installing Chromium instead of Chrome. Difference I found is the installation directory of both.

I installed Chrome and whereis Google-Chrome-Stable gives:

qa_user@jenkins:~$ whereis google-chrome-stable google-chrome-stable: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome-stable.1.gz

And qa_user@jenkins:~$ google-chrome-stable gives: google-chrome-stable: command not found

Now for Chromium:

qa_user@jenkins:~$ whereis chromium-browser gives: chromium-browser: /usr/bin/chromium-browser /usr/lib/chromium-browser /etc/chromium-browser /usr/share/chromium-browser /usr/share/man/man1/chromium-browser.1.gz

and qa_user@jenkins~$ chromium-browser [21304:21304:0607/135202.629230:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1473)] Unable to open X display. Identifies and opens Chromium (X display issue can be solved by adding --headless option in actual Selenium code).

So I am gonna use Chromium instead of Chrome until I/Someone here find the fix for the actual Chrome issue here.