# Selenium Chromedriver: Cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium), I explicitly gave the path to the Chrome Binary, but I am still getting the "Cannot fine chrome binary" error:

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path=path)
```

Location of Chrome Binary on my computer:

[image]

Location of ChromeDriver on my computer:

[image]

The error I am getting:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

My browser says I have an updated version but not sure if that impacts the binary as mentioned in the comment by Arundeep.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

I finally got it to work. There were two things that I had to do.

I placed the Chromedriver.exe into the same folder as Chrome.exe. This gave me a new error. "Selenium: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':"

Then I downloaded Chromedriver again and I realized what my mistake might have been. While unzipping ChromeDriver, initially I might have clicked "skip" when it asked me if I wanted to replace the existing file. This time I didn't and it worked.

Comment: chrome_options is depreciated use options instead.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Yeah, I had changed it but still got the same error. Let me edit it in the question. Thx

Comment: Don't think you have the latest binary for the newest chome version.

Comment: So, I should just update chrome? How do I get the latest binary for Chrome? I'll google this in the mean time.

Comment: If im reading well, your chrome driver is from 2015 and its 2.15.xx you need the latest. From here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/