# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I know a lot of people asked this question here and i looked at all of them but still i couldn't fix it. My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('http://web.whatsapp.com')
```

Error is :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

My code is actually copy-pasted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium/50140554) but it is still not working

Comment: try this `options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything