# Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound: Failed to find Chrome binary

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webdriver

I am trying to run a system test and keep running in this error:

rails aborted!
Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound: Failed to find Chrome binary.
/home/hasani/PROJECTS/hasani_pos/test/application_system_test_case.rb:4:in `<class:ApplicationSystemTestCase>' /home/hasani/PROJECTS/hasani_pos/test/application_system_test_case.rb:3:in` '
/home/hasani/PROJECTS/hasani_pos/test/system/items_test.rb:1:in `<main>' /home/hasani/PROJECTS/hasani_pos/bin/rails:5:in` <top (required)>'
/home/hasani/PROJECTS/hasani_pos/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>' /home/hasani/PROJECTS/hasani_pos/bin/spring:7:in` <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:system
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

items_test.rb

```
require "application_system_test_case"

class ItemsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test "visiting the index" do
    visit '/items'
    assert_selector "h1", text: "Items"
  end

  test "creating an item" do
    visit '/items'
    click_on "Create Item"
    assert_template 'new'
  end
end
```

test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/reporters"
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/minitest'
require 'webdrivers'
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  # Make `assert_*` methods behave like Minitest assertions
  include Capybara::Minitest::Assertions

  # Reset sessions and driver between tests
  teardown do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Item Index') %>
<h1>Item Index</h1>
  
  <a href="/add" class="btn btn-primary">Create Item</a>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </thead>
        </tr>
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= item.name %></td>
            <td><%= item.description %></td>
            <td><%= item.price %></td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to "Edit", edit_item_path(item) %>
              <%= link_to "Delete", 
                          item_path(item), method: :delete, 
                          "data-confirm": "Are you sure you want to delete?" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>  
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Create Item</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_msg' %>  

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
   
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
      
      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.number_field :price %>
      
      <%= f.submit "Create Item", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

It means webdriver is unable to find google chrome. Do you have the browser installed?

For minimal ubuntu development you only need this package:

`sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`

Or [later versions can be downloaded](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads) ([set-up tips](https://makandracards.com/makandra/29465-install-chromedriver-on-linux))

Answer (score 2):

Basically what the error says is that the webdriver is unable to find google chrome. Make sure you have installed it in the correct place on your machine.

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium) goes into more detail about it, with the exception of being ruby over python: