# chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed error using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Before I begin: I know there are a billion posts about Selenium not working, and various solutions to try. I believe I've tried everything, but forgive me if I am missing something. I'm hitting my head against a wall and would appreciate help.

Here are some steps I have taken:

I downloaded the chromedriver for selenium (Ubuntu, Python) and used `chmod 755` and also `chmod 777` to make the driver executable. Afterwords, I started the chromedriver with `./chromedriver`.

I've tried various options for Selenium, including manually adding the port that the chromedriver is running on

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/home/myname/projects/myproject/chromedriver"
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9515")
chrome_driver_binary = '/home/myname/projects/myproject/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options = options)
driver.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
```

I've tried options suggested in other posts, like these:

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
```

I've made sure that I am using a chromedriver that is compatable with my version of Chrome.

Nothing has seemed to work. I keep getting this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /home/myname/projects/myproject/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I'd sincerely appreciate someone else's interpretation of this problem.

Comment: I would recommend using the headless option and in a project ive used the .implicitly_wait(10) function before calling any website. I would also choose chromium as driver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I gave up and tried Firefox instead, which I got working first try. This situation is still a mystery to me, and I appreciate anyone's opinions on what might be wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- *`options.binary_location`*: Refers to the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) binary location and is used if *Google Chrome* isn't installed at the default location. See: [WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary error with Selenium in Python for older versions of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium/50140554#50140554)
- *`--remote-debugging-port`*: If you aren't remote debugging, you can drop this argument safely.
- *`chrome_driver_binary`*: Referes to the absolute location of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) within your system.
- *`webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options = options)`*: Additionally you may like to add the *key* *executable_path* as as follows:

  ```
  chrome_driver_binary = '/home/myname/projects/myproject/chromedriver'
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, options = options)
  driver.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
  ```
- *`--no-sandbox`*, *`--headless`*, *`--disable-dev-shm-usage`*, *`--disable-setuid-sandbox`*, etc are optional settings which you may not require to start off.

The minimum code block to initiate a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/myname/projects/myproject/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get("http://www.ubuntu.com/")
```

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough response.