# Selenium Chrome binary path issue on macos

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to code a web scrapper in python. It is my first time using Selenium and I have trouble with it :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options= Options()
#chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' # path to Chrome binary


PROXY = "" #HOST:PORT
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f' --proxy-server={PROXY}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

I then have the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

I have tried re-installing Google Chrome and chromedriver and their versions are up-to-date.

```
ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63
Google Chrome 113.0.5672.92
```

I am unfamiliar with web scrapping so it might be an obvious mistake from my part, I have no idea.

Comment: Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138615/webdriverexception-unknown-error-cannot-find-chrome-binary-error-with-selenium